# Swift: can I add and subtract `dispatch_time_t` variables?

Tags: ios, swift, time, grand-central-dispatch

I need to do some time math in iOS, with Swift.

I have to use `dispatch_walltime`. I hope that can be taken as axiomatic. Where time math is concerned, I think I'm likely to get the response "just use `NSDate`," but please take it on faith: I am bound to `dispatch_walltime`.

Now, it's plain why someone might suggest `NSDate`, because when you're using `NSTimeInterval` and `NSDate` and that good stuff, it's pretty easy to make custom timestamps and compare them and do all kinds of time math.

But I have to use `dispatch_time_t`, and specifically `dispatch_walltime` created like this:

```
//Get the timeInterval of now.
let nowInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

//Make a timespec from it.
var nowStruct = timespec(tv_sec: Int(nowInterval), tv_nsec: 0)

//Make a walltime definition from that.
let referenceWalltime = dispatch_walltime(&nowStruct, 0)
```

Later on I need to use that reference time in various ways. For instance, I need to get the time interval between the reference time and whatever time it happens to be.

I am attempting to do this the same way I would with `NSTimeInterval`, in other words, make a new one and subtract the old one from it:

```
//Repeat everything from before to make a new wall time.
let newNowInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
var newNowStruct = timespec(tv_sec: Int(newNowInterval), tv_nsec: 0)
let newWalltime = dispatch_walltime(& newNowStruct, 0)

//Time math a la NSTimeInterval to find the interval:
let walltimeInterval = newWalltime - referenceWalltime
```

Will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: no. That code will crash.

The better answer is: no, but it can be done, and it's not all that different in the end.

I did some investigating on my own in a Playground and learned some interesting things, and I believe I figured out the right way to do this.

I'm pasting the entirety of my Playground here, so that others can copy-paste it and figure out how to do their own `dispatch_time` math.

Comments marked by //********* in the code denote the key things I learned.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(continueIndefinitely: true)

public class IntervalMaker {

    var referenceWalltime: dispatch_time_t = 0
    var newWalltime: dispatch_time_t = 0
    var walltimeInterval: dispatch_time_t = 0

    func scheduleWalltimeSequence () {
         let threeSeconds = Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 3
         let now = walltimeNow()
         let dispatchTimeInThree = dispatch_time(now, threeSeconds)
         let dispatchTimeInSix = dispatch_time(now,
             2 * threeSeconds)
         setReferenceWalltimeToNow()
         dispatch_after(dispatchTimeInThree, dispatch_get_main_queue(),
             setNewWalltimeToNow)
         dispatch_after(dispatchTimeInSix,
             dispatch_get_main_queue(), dispatchBasedOnDispatchMath)
    }

    func walltimeNow()->dispatch_time_t{
         let nowInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
         var nowStruct = timespec(tv_sec: Int(nowInterval), tv_nsec: 0)
         return dispatch_walltime(&nowStruct, 0)
    }

    func setReferenceWalltimeToNow () {
         referenceWalltime = walltimeNow()
    }

    func setNewWalltimeToNow (){
         newWalltime = walltimeNow()
    }

    func dispatchBasedOnDispatchMath () {
         computeInterval() //Should be three seconds
         let nineTheWrongWay = referenceWalltime + (walltimeInterval * 3)
         let nineTheRightWay = dispatch_time(referenceWalltime,
             Int64(walltimeInterval) * 3)
         dispatch_after(nineTheWrongWay,
             dispatch_get_main_queue(), finalPrintln)
//********** THE ABOVE DOES NOT WORK CORRECTLY - prints 6 seconds later
         dispatch_after(nineTheRightWay,
             dispatch_get_main_queue(), finalPrintln)
//********** THE ABOVE WORKS CORRECTLY - prints 9 seconds later
    }

    func finalPrintln () {
        let now = walltimeNow()
        println("I should be printing nine seconds from reference time.")
        println("It's actually \(referenceWalltime - now) nanoseconds after")
    }

    func computeInterval () {
        walltimeInterval = referenceWalltime - newWalltime
//********** dispatch_walltimes actually count backwards, and *CANNOT* be
//********** negative: writing `newWalltime - referenceWalltime` will crash
    }
}

 let intervaller = IntervalMaker()
 intervaller.scheduleWalltimeSequence()
```